# Find matrix such that Ker and Im is given a equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm studying linear algebra and I came across this exercise.

Find a matrix $A \in M_{4\times4}$ such that:

$Ker(A) = Im(A) = \{ (x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^4: x-y+2w = 0, z=0 \}$

Right now, the only thing I've gotten is an array whose kernel is equal to the one requested. But I don't know how to make the image as requested.

Sorry by my english, I'not native.